# WiFi connection via network bridge intermittent

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-bridge, bridge-router

Infrastructure: old router is configured as network bridge with WiFi on.

Issue: seems the router is selective about what data is passed to only WiFi devices. E.g: phone can reach tweets but not comments. Can reach Play store, but can't search for apps - only the ones on the homescreen

Could there be a selective/ filtered route on upstream traffic?

Furthermore, when the bridge is turned on, the firestick connected to the primary router acts fucky

Hope someone here can help.

Comment: Make sure the old router has the same Wi-Fi specifications, at least common elements. Update the firmware in the old router. Remember that operating it as a bridge or repeater will likely cut the bandwidth in half.

Comment: @john, repeater yes. Bridge no. Bridging usually just puts the wireless card into station mode. Unless of course it's a "WDS Bridge" which shouldn't really be called a bridge honestly.

Comment: What's the make/model of the problematic router in bridge mode?

Answer (score 0):

I actually resolved the issue, wish I knew how and could share here but I basically turned off the 5GHz wifi signal and the Router Advertisement settings. Doubt the 5G signal made a difference but wasn't needed in this corner of the house. No reduction in bandwidth either.

The set up supports WiFi and LAN and there doesn't seem to be any impact to other devices connected to the primary router & 1 Terabyte SSD plugged into the switch to replace G Drive.

If I can grasp what exactly changed I'll post a walkthrough and link it here for you guys.

I'm also planning to add a DynDNS config so might save the YT vid for that and show it all.